# INT 13h cannot read beyond specific sector

Tags: assembly, x86-16, osdev, bios

I am writing a kernel for my operating system and I have ran into a problem while loading a sector of a disk to memory.

Here is the portion of the code of the function that loads the sector from the disk:

```c
        mov     ax, #0x3000
        mov     es, ax

        mov     ax, #0x0201
        mov     bx, word ptr [bp - 6]   ; bx = 0x000, 0x200, 0x400, ...
        xor     ch, ch
        mov     cl, byte ptr [bp - 8]   ; cl = target cluster to read
        xor     dx, dx
        int     0x13

        jc      load_cluster_carry      ; carry == 1 when error            
        xor     ax, ax
        inc     ax
        jmp     load_cluster_end
load_cluster_carry:
        xor   ax, ax
load_cluster_end:
        mov     word ptr [bp - 10], ax
```

And the function cannot read from sector 19. So I checked AH register and its value was 0x01.

Comment: Presumably you're using a 90mm style 1440 KiB diskette. This has a CHS geometry of 80 Cylinders, 2 Heads, 18 Sectors. So reading from `cl & 3Fh` = sector 19 is invalid. You have to calculate a valid CHS tuple, not ignorantly increment one of the involved registers.

Comment: Or maybe use `ah = 08h` `int 13h`- reading drive parameters and see what max CHS values You can use :)

Comment: @ecm I'll try, thanks! Where did you get this information though?

Comment: @NatsciT Some of it is described in references like Ralf Brown's Interrupt List, eg http://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/bios/1302.html Another resource is the osdev wiki: https://wiki.osdev.org/Disk_access_using_the_BIOS_(INT_13h)

Comment: @0Signal I didn't know that ah = 08h existed. Thanks for telling me that. :)

Comment: Having access to Ralf Brown's famous [Interrupt List](https://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) is a must.

Comment: @ecm I changed the value of `dx` register and it worked! Thank you alot. (I think my reply got deleted somehow so I'm writing this again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov     ax, #0x0201
> mov     bx, word ptr [bp - 6]   ; bx = 0x000, 0x200, 0x400, ...
> xor     ch, ch
> mov     cl, byte ptr [bp - 8]   ; cl = target cluster to read
> xor     dx, dx
> int     0x13
> ```

The comment `; bx = 0x000, 0x200, 0x400, ...` tells us that you want to read multiple sectors. From `xor ch, ch` (CH for Cylinder) and `xor dx, dx` (DH for Head), we can conclude that you seem to expect to find all of those sectors on the same Cylinder (0) and Head (0). This will not be the case: at some point you will have read all the available sectors on the current track and you will need to advance to the next track.

The answer at [How are all disk sectors iterated in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990880/how-are-all-disk-sectors-iterated-in-assembly) has a working code that shows how to do that correctly. The code does not guess about the disk's geometry and asks BIOS for these values.

Your `xor dx, dx` also zeroes the DL register that specifies the drive to use. Unless you are very sure that it needs to be 0, I would advice that instead you use the value that BIOS gave you when your bootloader got started. The drive id is passed to you in the DL register, and BTW it's the only information that BIOS provides when your bootloader begins.

### Extra trick

> ```
>    jc      load_cluster_carry      ; carry == 1 when error            
>    xor     ax, ax
>    inc     ax
>    jmp     load_cluster_end
> load_cluster_carry:
>    xor   ax, ax
> load_cluster_end:
>    mov     word ptr [bp - 10], ax
> ```

You can replace the above by next simpler/cleaner code:

```
cmc
sbb  ax, ax
neg  ax
mov  [bp - 10], ax
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I would like to upvote but I can't because I do not have sufficient reputation..