# Why doesn't the bootloader completely?

Tags: assembly, kernel, x86-16, bootloader, fasm

I’m trying to load resources, but it doesn’t load (?) It can fully answer what exactly is happening to it, it doesn’t give errors, but it doesn’t work like that, it doesn’t respond to the command, it just outputs, while the entor entered what. This behavior manifested itself after the value of the coefficient increased.

dumpbin when the kernel was running:

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    3FE1 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00011000 to 00014FE0)
    4000 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000043FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
    1046 virtual size
    5000 virtual address (00015000 to 00016045)
     200 size of raw data
    4400 file pointer to raw data (00004400 to 000045FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

SECTION HEADER #3
.data/IG name
    1E90 virtual size
    7000 virtual address (00017000 to 00018E8F)
    2000 size of raw data
    4600 file pointer to raw data (00004600 to 000065FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only
```

dumpbin, after I added a function to the kernel that counts ticks, after it the kernel itself increased and stopped working correctly :

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    4031 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00011000 to 00015030)
    4200 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000045FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
    1046 virtual size
    6000 virtual address (00016000 to 00017045)
     200 size of raw data
    4600 file pointer to raw data (00004600 to 000047FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

SECTION HEADER #3
.data/IG name
    1E90 virtual size
    8000 virtual address (00018000 to 00019E8F)
    2000 size of raw data
    4800 file pointer to raw data (00004800 to 000067FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only
```

загрузка ядра

```
use16
org 0x7C00
start:
mov ax, cs 
mov ds, ax  
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, start  

mov ax, cs 
mov ds, ax  
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, start 

mov ax, 0x1100
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1 
mov dh, 0 
mov ch, 0 
mov cl, 3
mov al, 33
mov ah, 0x02 
int 0x13

mov ax, 0x1600
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1
mov dh, 0
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 36
mov al, 1
mov ah, 0x02

int 0x13
mov ah, 0
mov al, 2
int 0x10

mov ax, 0x1800
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1
mov dh, 0
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 37
mov al, 16
mov ah, 0x02
int 0x13 

  lgdt [gdt_info]
in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al    
mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp 0x8:protected_mode 
gdt:
db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
;base=0, size=4Gb, P=1, DPL=0, S=1(user),
;Type=1(code), Access=00A, G=1, B=32bit
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0xCF, 0x00
;base=0, size=4Gb, P=1, DPL=0, S=1(user),
;Type=0(data), Access=0W0, G=1, B=32bit
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x92, 0xCF, 0x00
gdt_info: 
dw gdt_info - gdt
dw gdt, 0
use32
protected_mode:
mov ax, 0x10
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
call 0x11000
times (512 - ($ - start) - 2) db 0 
db 0x55, 0xAA
```

function that reads ticks

```
__declspec(naked) void timer()
{
    __asm pusha;
    ticks++;
    outb(PIC1_PORT, 0x20);
    __asm {
        popa
        iretd
    }
}

void init_ticks(){
    intr_reg_handler(8, GDT_CS, 0x80 | IDT_TYPE_INTR, timer); // Регистрация обработчика прерывания (segm_sel=0x8, P=1, DPL=0, Type=Intr)
    outb(PIC1_PORT + 1, 0xFF ^ 0x01);
    }
```

Translator: FASM, assembler: Intel, compiler: ms c

i try load correct data in bootloader but it still doesnt work

Comment: What kind of media are you booting from? With DL=1 it almost looks like floppy media (1=second floppy drive). What kind of floppy?  Is it even a floppy? I ask because `mov cl, 36` doesn't look like it should work (for most floppy media) since most floppy media don't have anywhere near 36 sectors per track. 2.88MiB floppies being an exception but they were formatted with 36 sectors per track. Have you verified that the disk reads you are doing haven't failed? (If they fail Int 0x13/AH=2 will set the CarryFlag(CF) and AH will have an error code with the reason)

Comment: I agree with Michael. I believe zx485 is wanting to read 33 sectors from LBA 3, 1 sector from LBA 36, and then 16 sectors from LBA 37, not knowing that, for floppies, you have to convert this LBA to CHS. If it was me, I would write a ReadSectors() routine that is passed the LBA in dx:ax and a count in cx.  Then in this routine, convert the LBA to CHS (if indeed it is a floppy after all), and then call the BIOS disk read service. Remember that there is a limit to how many sectors you can read at one time using CHS.

Comment: Going through recent previous posts, I found [int-13h-cannot-read-beyond-specific-sector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76877105/int-13h-cannot-read-beyond-specific-sector). It has a few similar comments you may wish to read.

Comment: @МайклПетч magnetic disc

Comment: @Фиснет And where can I read about it? How to arrange all this correctly? I just don't understand a little bit

Comment: Is the media a floppy disk or a hard drive? They can and usually are both magnetic disks. (with a k, not a c). If it is a floppy disk, search how to convert a zero-based LBA to a one-based CHS triple. It is fairly easy to do so. One example I have uses 13 lines of assembly to convert a 32-bit LBA to a CHS triple. Floppy disks/drives use a CHS value, Cylinder/Head/Sector. You can read from any Cylinder, one head at a time, and one or more sectors from that track at a time. You cannot cross track boundaries. Sometimes you can read from both sides of the same track (Cylinder) per request.

Comment: If it is a hard disk, you can use another BIOS Disk service and provide the LBA value instead. You first check to see if the service is available, then if found, give a 48-bit LBA address, reading up to 7Fh sectors at a time, no more. (Watch for 64k boundary crossing)